# Watchman Installation

Tags: system-installation

```
pkg-config appears to be missing (not available to autoconf tools) please install the pkg-config package for your system.
bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Which Ubuntu version is this? What command are you running to this error to appear? Have you updated your system? `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install pkg-config.

   ```
   sudo apt install pkg-config
   ```

   If the problem is solved you're done, otherwise continue to step 2.
2. Install watchman.

   ```
   sudo apt install -y libssl-dev autoconf automake libtool build-essential python-dev 
   cd $HOME
   git clone https://github.com/facebook/watchman.git -b v4.9.0 --depth 1
   cd watchman
   ./autogen.sh
   ./configure
   make
   sudo make install
   ```